# JUnit NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: junit, noclassdeffounderror

I'm new at JUnit and use inteliji idea.

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.Ignore;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.JUnit4;
import java.util.Date;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
public class TestQuote {
    @Test
    public void testQuote() {
        Date date = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
        Quote quote=new Quote("a",date,200.0,300.0,100.0,107.0,1.0);
        assertNull("Object is null",quote);
        assertEquals("Symbol is ok",quote.getSymbol(),"a");
        assertEquals("Date is ok",quote.getDate(),System.currentTimeMillis());
        assertEquals("Open price is ok",quote.getOpenPrice(),200.0);
        assertEquals("High price is ok",quote.getHighPrice(),300.0);
        assertEquals("Low price is ok",quote.getLowPrice(),100.0);
        assertEquals("Close price is ok",quote.getClosePrice(),107.0);
    }
}
```

Here is code of my test class. JUnit.jar is added to classpath but when i run it it says:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hamcrest/SelfDescribing
```

Any sollutions?
BTW main program work OK.

Comment: you don't have all of junit in your classpath.

Comment: i've added junit.jar in File->Project Structure. What's next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the JUnit web site: http://junit.org/

Then click on "Download and install Guide" : https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Download-and-Install

Then read:

> Download the following JARs and put them on your test classpath:
>
> - junit.jar
> - hamcrest-core.jar